# How do I get Sphinx to markup C calls in text the way the standard Python docs do?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

In the standard Python documentation, system calls appear as bold, fixed-width font. You can see this in the asyncore section, when it mentions **`select()`** or **`poll()`** for example:

http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/asyncore.html

I checked the source code for asyncore, and it has no special markups for these functions, so I'm not sure how one convinces Sphinx to do this. Is there a simple directive I can add to index.rst to make this work like I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you see that there is no special markup for the C function calls? When I looked at the [latest source for this file](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/f8e7fe70c075/Doc/library/asyncore.rst) it has `:cfunc:'select'`, which I think is [old style](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/latest/ext/oldcmarkup.html) Sphinx markup for C code. For the latest way of doing it read up on [The C Domain](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/latest/domains.html#c-domain).

Comment: Ah, okay. For some reason I was thinking that it was using docstring, since the source code that you get when you click on the "source code" link on the documentation starts with the same text as the HTML documentation. Looking at your link I see the separate file with documentation.

`:cfunc:` is exactly what I wanted!

Thanks!